# Android - How to make Async task run before Picasso image download?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have an async task that download data from webpage using HTTPClient. The problem is while the Picasso is downloading image, the async task must wait for the image downloading to be done.

How could I make the async task run before the image downloading?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        //Set the Bitmap into any views if you want.
        // Start AsyncTask Here. 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed() {

    }
}

private void someMethod() { 
    Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}
```

Comment: But I run AsyncTask in an OnScrollListener and Picasso in ArrayAdapter. What should I do ?

Comment: I think you put the bitmap in some view of the array adapter ?

Comment: Hi, I run AsyncTask in an OnScrollListener and Picasso in ArrayAdapter

Comment: Put some Boolean flag which is accessible to the ArrayAdapter as well as the onScrollListener. Set it to true inside the onBitmapLoaded() method. Check if the flag is true inside the onScrollListener before executing the AsyncTask.

Comment: Hi, I want to do this : while scrolling the list, ArrayAdapter display the image via picasso. But the network is slow, then images load slow. If I scroll to the end of the list, images are still loading, and the AsyncTask has to wait for all the images to be loaded in order to run. How could I make the AsyncTask run first ?

Comment: what does your async task do ? and when do you want to execute it. Can you put some code in the question to make things clearer.